# Should I apply to a job knowing it's temporary?

Tags: professionalism, employment-gaps, applications

I have been out of work for about a year, and for the last six months have been operating a sole-prop consulting business and digital agency. While it pays the bills, money is getting tight and the runway is nearing an end. I've applied to many jobs in my area but have been getting a slow return of rejections. On top of this, my health care expires this month. I don't know which makes more sense, moving forward:

Get a low-paying job that offers benefits on day 1 (taking care of money and healthcare for the time being), keeping other opportunities in mind. There is a warehouse opportunity near me and I'm in good physical shape for the position. I wouldn't need a reference or anything, it would only be used for healthcare and financial stability.

Continue waiting to hear back from my other applications. I've sent out around 20 applications over the last couple months and have gotten back 4 rejections. All applications were done through websites like Indeed and Monster. I don't know how long it will take to hear back from them, and there's no guarantee that I will even get a second interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always easier to get a job when you have a job.  More than once, a "temporary" job has gone full-time perm for me.  I also once took a job to get my foot in the door so that I could apply for other positions in my field as an internal candidate.

Never let an opportunity pass by, you never know what additional doors it may open for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to go with safe bets and guarantees. Going with what will keep you financially stable should be your best option, while looking for something better. It wouldn't make sense to pass up an opportunity while waiting for an unknown better situation to present itself. Keep plugging away on the job hunt and keep the temp job to facilitate not having any hardships or trouble while you search.